Second order ODE solution approach
Find a solution for the following second order ODE
$$x''(t)+(x'(t))^2+\sin(x(t))=0, \; x(0)=\pi,\;x'(0)=0.$$
I am familiar with the characteristics equations method or assuming $y=e^{rx}$, however both approaches seem unavailable for this equation.
I tried simplifying the equation by assuming that we only seek a solution around the point $x(0)=\pi$ and therefore $\sin(x)\approx-x$, which reduces the problem to
$$x''+(x')^2-x=0.$$
From here I still don't see how to work around $(x')^2$

Hint: it's a trick question, made to look much harder than it is. Evaluate $x''(0)$ and then think about it.

Its an exam problem from course about deeper ODE theory

Don't try to find the general solution. Follow @Ian's hint.

...is it from your exam, or a past exam?

I see that $x'(0)=x''(0)=0$, so we have an inlection point and stationary point in 0, but I don't see how that implies that the solution is constant for all arguments. The problem is from my past exam which I couldn't solve

"... but I don't see how that implies that the solution is constant for all arguments." It doesn't. I think Ian was trying to point you towards a guess, rather than give you a logical argument ending in a constant solution.

@Ian I couldn't get my head around the conditions $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=0$: certainly any perturbative expansion around $\pi$ gives the solution $x=\pi$ to all orders. But your comment made me realise that the boundary conditions and full differential equation itself also imply that $x^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all natural numbers $n$.

@Weyr124 It doesn't imply that there is no other solution; you would need to invoke a uniqueness theorem of some kind for that. But you weren't asked for that. You were just asked to find one.

Remark: This is not the pendulum equation with friction term, because the physically correct model for that has $|x'(t)|,x'(t)$ as the second term.

"I am familiar with ..."  Those are methods for linear DEs, but this one is not linear.

The problem asks for a solution. Find one easiest, simplest solution.
If $x''(t)=0$ and $x'(t)=0$ then the equation becomes:
$$\sin(x(t))=0, \; x(0)=\pi$$
One solution is $x(t) = \pi$. My apologies for not being very mathy, but trivial solutions aren't wrong.

The boundary conditions $x(0)=\pi$ and $x'(0)=0$ imply that $x^{(n)}(0)=0$ to all orders giving credence to this solution. Also numerically solving the full ODE in Mathematica suggests that the trivial solution is in this case the full solution.

I don't follow the logic behind your first sentence about boundary conditions in isolation from the differential equation. For example, $$x(t) = e^{-t}+t+\pi-1$$ has $x(0) = \pi$ and $x'(0) = 0$, but $x''(0)=1$.

The differential equation informs $x’’(t)=-sin(x(t))-x’’(t)$. Evaluation at $t=0$  and using the boundary conditions implies $x’’(0)=0$. Further differentiation of the differential equation gives the rest

I believe I see it now. The differential equation informs $x''(t) = -sin(x(t))-(x'(t))^2$. Using the boundary conditions implies $x''(0)=0$. Further differentiation yields $x^{(3)}(t) = -cos(x(t))x'(t)-2(x'(t))x''(t)$ which yields $x^{(3)}(0)=0$, and further differentiation always yields a sum of terms which have previously been shown to be zero, so $x^{(n)}(0)=0$.

Let us try parametrization: $p(x)\equiv x'(t)\implies x''(t)=pp'(x)$. The ODE then becomes
$$pp'(x)+p^2+\sin(x)=0\overset{u(x)\equiv p^2}{\iff}\dfrac{1}{2}u'(x)+u+\sin(x)=0$$
Solving the homogeneous ODE we obtain
$$u_h(x)=Ae^{-2x}$$
By employing the method of variation of parameters $(u_p=A(x)e^{-x})$ we arrive at the full solution
$$u(x)=Ae^{-2x}-\dfrac{4\sin(x)}{5}+\dfrac{2\cos(x)}{5}$$
Reverting the substitution, we get this other ODE:
$$x'(t)^2=Ae^{-2x}-\dfrac{4\sin(x)}{5}+\dfrac{2\cos(x)}{5}.$$
Previous to separating variables, let's rather apply the derivative's initial condition $(x'(0)=0)$ in order to find $A$:
$$0=A+\dfrac{2}{5}\implies A=-\dfrac{2}{5}$$
Therefore,
$$\int_0^t\mathrm dt=\boxed{t=\int_\pi^x\dfrac{\pm\,\mathrm dx'}{\sqrt{-\dfrac{2}{5}e^{-2x'}-\dfrac{4\sin(x')}{5}+\dfrac{2\cos(x')}{5}}}},$$
where we already incorporated the remaining inital condition in the limits of integration.

I don't think think this can be correct. Note that the equation can be rewritten as $x'=p,p'=-p^2+\sin(x)$; that's a locally Lipschitz vector-valued function of $(p,x)$; so the solution to an IVP is unique.

I made an error, it should be $p'=-p^2-\sin(x)$, but that doesn't change the point.

Note that the square root in the denominator of your formal solution is strictly negative for $x \in (0, \pi]$, so this is not actually a valid solution to the ODE.  (The error being, of course, that the last step implicitly assumes that $x(t)$ is an invertible function;  so what this shows is that there is no solution for which $x(t)$ is invertible near $x = \pi$.)

Your initial value problem is of the form
$$X'=F(X),\quad X(0)=\begin{pmatrix}\pi\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ where $F:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is $C^1$ hence locally Lipschitz:
$$F\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v\\-v^2-\sin u\end{pmatrix}.$$ Therefore, by Picard–Lindelöf theorem, the maximal solution is unique.
Since $X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\pi\\0\end{pmatrix}$ is (obviously) a solution, it is the solution.

I knew that if F is locally lipschitz, then the solution is unique. I didn't know that $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbf{C}^1$ implies that $\mathbf{F}$ is lipschitz. Thank you.

Not Lipschitz. Locally Lipschitz. And the maximal solution is unique. You are welcome.

Forgetting the conditions, if you switch variables, the equation becomes
$$-\frac {t''}{[t']^3}+\frac {1}{[t']^2}+\sin(x)=0$$
Reduction of order
$$t'=\pm \frac{\sqrt{5}\, e^x}{\sqrt{2 e^{2 x} \cos (x)-4 e^{2 x} \sin (x)+ c_1}} $$
$$t+c_2=\pm \int \frac{\sqrt{5}\, e^x}{\sqrt{2 e^{2 x} \cos (x)-4 e^{2 x} \sin (x)+ c_1}} $$

Note my comment on conreu's answer;  it implies that there do not exist constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ that satisfy the boundary conditions given.
